# WP7 main page loads twice

Tags: windows-phone-7

Anyone have an idea what would cause my MainPage to load twice in WP7?

I looked at whats in the callstack both times in the MainPage constructor and I don't see any difference.  Also the OnNavigateTo() event fires twice, but the OnNavigatingFrom() never fires.

Comment: would be good to see your code. Or You created a new project and it is so?

Comment: yup, need more info.  you aren't calling navigate on anything?

Comment: That's the problem, I have no idea what code to post.  It's my initial startup page, so its navigated to automatically. I

Comment: If you find an answer, then it's better to post that answer (and accept it) rather than to edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how that was suppose to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my App.xml I had this

< !--RootFrame points to and loads the first page of your application-->
< Application.RootVisual>
< phone:PhoneApplicationFrame x:Name="RootFrame" />
< /Application.RootVisual>

When I removed it everything worked as it should